# Open loop cooling system

Tags: thermodynamics, flow

I am trying to find out the rate at which I need to pump water into a device generating a specific amount of heat to keep it at a low temperature. I have not taken thermodynamics yet, and so I am trying to use a very basic model. The water is pumped through a copper pipe.

I know the following:

- Temperature of incoming water
- length and diameter (both inner and outer) of the copper pipe
- The total heat being generated by the device

I am looking for an equation that will have these as independent variables and give me the needed flow rate of the water.

Again I am looking for a ballpark answer, so if there are some other assumptions I have to make, like uniform heating, I can get away with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Convective heat transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer) is a bit trickier than conduction.  It will depend quite a bit on the geometry and orientation of the flow relative to the heat source.  As is this question is a bit too broad.  I personally suggest just testing it yourself if possible.  It might be hard to do by hand without a good amount of heat transfer research (and even then, getting answers that are close to real life is another issue).